# How do I generate a file using the mac os9 line terminators?

Tags: java, python

I need a 10MB file for testing. It needs to be line terminated with

```
\r
```

I believe that unixes uses `\n` and windows uses `\r\n`.
How do I generate this file in python or java ?

Comment: Does it have to be *exactly* 10MB?

Comment: Are you just creating the new line characters or will there be anything else on the line?

Comment: Around 10MB is fine. Each line could contain "Hello World" or some random string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open("mac", "wb") as f:
    for ind in xrange(1000000):
        f.write("a" * 9 + "\r")
```

The 'b' prevents Windows from screwing up your line endings.

On Python 3, it also means you have to write bytes instead of strings to the file.  As a consequence, you need to change the last line to:

```
f.write(b"a" * 9 + b"\r")
```

Also for Python 3, `xrange` should be `range`.

Comment: +1, but I would avoid using `_` as the loop variable name, since `_` is used in interactive mode for the value of the last expression.

Comment: ITYM `f.write(b'a' * 9 + b'\r'` for 3.x?

Answer (score -2):

if you already have a file that's ~10MB and have Perl available, its as easy as:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\n/\r/' file.txt
```

where file.txt is the file you want to operate on.  this will replace every lf with a cr.  if you open the file in vi or something else that lets you see eol characters, it should look like one really long line with ^M in there wherever there had been a new line break before.

Comment: He specifically asked for Java and Python, and if you're writing a Perl solution, why not just output the file?  It will probably have better performance than regex over 10 MB.

Comment: @Matthew because I assume the only reason he's asking for a solution in those languages is because they're the only ones he knows.  I also expect that he has at least one 10MB text file that can just be modified.  why do any more than you have to when i'm pretty sure he wants the file to use to test something else and doesn't intend to generate the file as a goal in and of itself.

Comment: What makes you so sure he has a 10 MB text (no nulls) file?  He probably has binaries, but that doesn't help.  Anyway, why make him find it when he asked to generate one?